# I need to rewrite c++ 11 code in c++98, c++ 11 is using lambda function [&](const Output & o

Tags: c++, c++98

I need to migrate this c++98 code snippet to C++11 to a lambda function

```
std::for_each(m_outputs.begin(), m_outputs.end(), [&](const Output & o)
{
     process(o)
}
```

Comment: What's `process`? Also, have you tried tackling this yourself?

Comment: If you can get rid of the lambda capture you can just use a regular function, otherwise a `struct` with an `operator()`.

Comment: Why do you want to use 20 year old C++?

Comment: process is a bunch of calls on o. I do know operator but cant find proper syntax to write capture

Comment: If the point of the question is the capture, then why did you remove all captured variables from the lambda body??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a pointless use of lambda's anyway:

`std::for_each(m_outputs.begin(), m_outputs.end(), &process);`

That said, a lambda is just an object with an `operator()`. You can always write the underlying type manually, and create an instance. Lambda's save lines of code, but are not magic.

[edit]
Since we've learned that the question is about captures, `[&]` captures variables by reference. That means adding one or more reference variable to the replacement type you're writing.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there's zero need to actually use a `std` algorithm and functor here. Assuming `TheType` is the type which `m_outputs.begin()` returns, you can easily rewrite the code as follows:

```
for (
  TheType it = m_outputs.begin(), itEnd = m_outputs.end();
  it != itEnd;
  ++it
) {
  process(*it);
}
```